# How to validate a given time interval against a time table in python?

Tags: python, intervals, python-datetime

I wrote some lines of code (python 3.7) to check for a given **point** in time, which timeslot in a time table it matches. For this purpose I use pythons `datetime` module. My problem is that I don't know how to check this for a **period** in time. I ran through a lot of related subjects while searching for an answer, but I could not find anything that comes close enough.

I got this working for a **point in time** (timestamp)

*pseudo code*:

```
time_point = 11:00
timeslot_1 = 10:00 - 12:00
timeslot_2 = 12:00 - 14:00

def check_interval(time_unit):
    if time_unit within timeslot_1:
      return timetable_interval_1
    if time_unit within timeslot_2:
      return timetable_interval_2
    else:
      return False

check_interval(time_point)
```

#### output:

```
10:00 - 12:00
```

But I would like to know this for a **period in time** (interval between two timestamps)

*pseudo code*:

```
time_period = 11:00 - 12:30
timeslot_1 = 10:00 - 12:00
timeslot_2 = 12:00 - 14:00

def check_interval(time_unit):
    if time_unit within timeslot_1:
      return timeslot_1
    if time_unit within timeslot_2:
      return timeslot_2
    if time_unit within timeslot_1 and within timeslot_2:
      return timeslot_1 + timeslot_2
    else:
      return False

check_interval(time_period)
```

#### output

```
10:00 - 14:00
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `time` to define time points, and tuples of times to represent intervals. For example:

```
from datetime import time

time_period = time(11), time(12, 30)
timeslot_1 = time(10), time(12)
timeslot_2 = time(12), time(14)

def check_interval(period):
    if timeslot_1[0] <= period[0] <= period[1] <= timeslot_1[1]:
      return timeslot_1
    if timeslot_2[0] <= period[0] <= period[1] <= timeslot_2[1]:
      return timeslot_2
    if timeslot_1[0] <= period[0] <= period[1] <= timeslot_2[1]:
      return timeslot_1[0], timeslot_2[1]
    else:
      return False

print(check_interval((time(11), time(12, 30))))
# prints (datetime.time(10, 0), datetime.time(14, 0))

print(check_interval((time(9), time(12, 30))))
# prints False
```